# Is it possible to change the PATH variable for a specific user in a single place and have it available on console and GUI applications too?

Tags: path, environment-variables

I am looking for a solution that would allow me to modify PATH for single OS X user but have the PATH available not only to console applications but also to GUI applications.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Adding a tool to the PATH so it can be accesible even for IDEs ?! ... and I do not want to have two places where to manage the PATH.

Comment: The solution here should work: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51677/how-to-set-path-for-finder-launched-applications

Comment: @ReneLarsen none of the solutions worked.

Comment: How is this different than your other question here? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63662/how-to-change-path-environment-variable-to-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion-that-will-be