# How to change PATH environment variable to OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion that will be visible to GUI applications?

Tags: macos, path, environment-variables

I tried all methods I heard of for setting environment variables on OS X 10.8 but none of them seems to work.

To test, run a bash script from inside a gui application like Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA.

```
#!/bin/bash
set|grep PATH
```

Things I tested and that are **not working** even after reboot:

- `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d/something`
- `/etc/launchd.conf`
- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` (binary plist made as recommended)
- running `launchctl setenv PATH $PATH` from the command line, this was supposed to update the PATH for GUI apps, at least for current session. Guess what, no change.

It seems that PATH is always `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` for GUI apps.

Comment: Are you OK with a solution that sets the bash path or do you really need to change launchd's value of the base path for all processes?

Comment: I need to change the PATH used by GUI apps, for terminal/bash/... I already have a big set of working solutions.

Comment: I don't know why eclipse and others don't just support [runtime environment variables](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/EnvironmentVars.html) so every java developer on Mac doesn't need to worry about setting the path or sourcing in their desired variables in each project.

Comment: answer see here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51677/how-to-set-path-for-finder-launched-applications/79845#79845

Answer (score 8):

With Mountain Lion `/etc/launchd.conf` is where you should set the GUI applications Path. Remember it's not a script file; it only supports `launchctl` commands so you should write something like:

```
setenv PATH /new/path:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Note also that it doesn't support shell environment variable substitutions (like `$PATH`) so you'll have to set every path that you want to include. It's a good idea to keep the original paths that you've mentioned (`/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`).

You'll have to reboot after changing (or creating) the file for the changes to take effect.

Comment: This worked for me in 10.8.2 for setting a PATH which was usable with Keyboard Maestro.

Comment: The man page says that you can use $HOME/.launchd.conf but that did not work for me.  Using /etc/launchd.conf did.  I'm on 10.8.4

Comment: It doesn't work for me : `-bash: setenv: command not found`

Comment: If anyone was confused like Colas, `setenv` is a `launchctl` command, so you use it like `launchctl setenv`.

Answer (score 4):

It works if you call the GUI app from Terminal:

```
PATH=/this/is/kind/of/crazy:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin /Applications/Automator.app/Contents/MacOS/Automator
```

[image]

Not really nice or comfortable but it does the job if needed.

Comment: Shortly NO WAY. I am not willing to do this, it will work only sometimes. The app can also be started when you click on a file.

Comment: As I said it's not really nice but may work until Apple fixes the issue (because it *should* be possible with launchctl).

Answer (score 3):

I cooked up another solution, inspired by [patrix one here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/63685/30415), that hopefully is a little less painful. Open `Automator`, select an application as target, and choose `Execute Shell script` (or whatever it is called, in German it is "Shell-Skript ausführen" as can be seen above) as action. In the script, just type

```
launchctl setenv FOO1 bar1
[...]
launchctl setenv FOOn barn
open -a YourApplicationHere
```

Then save the whole thing wherever you want, and if you need to run *YourApplicationHere*, open the created "automator application" instead.

I tested this with `Terminal` as *YourApplicationHere*, and saw with `launchctl export` that **FOO** was indeed set to **bar**. I hope it works for others as well.

Finally, if you use [this](https://superuser.com/questions/476752/setting-environment-variables-in-os-x-for-gui-applications/476960#476960) solution for your environment variables, instead of typing the `launchctl` stuff in the shell script, you may just call `/Users/Shared/conflaunchd.sh` (which you have to make up first, together with the file describing the variables).

Answer (score -1):

Supposedly, `launchctl` provides `PATH` to GUI Apps. To set the path to that of shell path, add the following to your shell rc file after setting your path:

```
launchctl setenv PATH $PATH
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work :-(

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51677/how-to-set-path-for-finder-launched-applications/51678#51678

Comment: We allow answers that make a good faith effort to address the question. We even allow wrong answers and let the voting speak for correctness. Commenting without making it personal is the best way to poke a hole in a faulty argument rather than discouraging attempts to answer.