# In Mountain Lion how do I set, in one place, the PATH environment variable for all newly launched applications?

Tags: macos, path, environment-variables

On Ask Different there are many questions regarding the `PATH` environment variable and how to set it for applications launched by a shell, by spotlight or via the finder (typical questions: [How to set PATH for Finder-launched applications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51677/how-to-set-path-for-finder-launched-applications) or [How to change PATH environment variable...](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63662/how-to-change-path-environment-variable-to-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion-that-will-be)).

Answers range from *`sh` startup scripts* to *`/etc/paths`* to *`/etc/launchd.conf`*. Here I am after the answer for a *unified* setting of `PATH` for all apps under Mac OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.2.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After many trials with different options I conclude:

Is there a *unified way* to set the `PATH` for applications launched by different means (like shell script, Finder and Spotlight)? Well, yes and no:

- *No*: Setting `PATH` in shell start up scripts (e.g. `.bashrc`) works only for apps launched by shells.
- *No*: Setting `PATH` for the current `launchd` process via `launchctl setenv PATH <...>` does not work for me at all.
- ***Yes*: Setting `PATH` in `/etc/launchd.conf` (and restarting the system) will make the appropriate `PATH` visible in  applications launched by Spotlight, Dock and Finder and subsequently (local) shells.**
- ***No*: Remotely invoked shells do *not* inherit the environment.** (See [...why do remote shells via ssh do NOT inherit the environment..](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/88726/15340))

#### Notes for set-up of shells:

1. For correct functioning in *local* shells it is important to *switch off* the use of `/usr/libexec/path_helper`, because the default paths in `/etc/paths` might change the order of the paths in `PATH`.**
2. To accommodate *remote* shells you need to re-import the `launchd` environment into the shell. Use something like this in your `.bashrc`:

```sh
# the vexatious path stuff
eval $(launchctl export)
```

#### Unfortunate consequences of the whole issue are:

- No way to have these unified settings on a per user basis. (`~/.launchd.conf` does not work.)
- No easy way to construct the PATH from different sources using techniques like home directory expansion et al.

Comment: Update: Setting PATH via `/etc/launch.conf` does *not* work for shells logged into remotely via ssh (I assume because the `sshd` does not pass its environment it inherits from its parent `launchd` to the child shell.). - I will edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Answer updated with a solution for remote shells.

Comment: Great answer; You can simplify sourcing of the launchd environment as follows: `eval "$(launchctl export)"`.

Comment: An easy way to edit `/etc/launchd.conf` is to just run `sudo -e /etc/launchd.conf` (if you are familiar with vi) or `EDITOR=nano sudo -e /etc/launchd.conf` (if you prefer a non-modal editor).

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on [the previous answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/87283/23545), to change the path in `/etc/launchd.conf`, you'll need to do the following.

1. Make sure you have Administrator privileges.
2. Create a new text file with the following content, modified to fit your needs:

   ```
   setenv PATH /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/Users/YourUserName/bin
   ```
3. Save it *in your home directory* as `launchd.conf`.
4. Open Terminal.app (or your favorite substitute) and type:

   `sudo mv ~/launchd.conf /etc`

   Depending on your previous usage of the `sudo` command, you may get a short "be careful doing what you're doing" message, but either way you'll need to enter your password. All the command does is move the file to the `/etc` directory, which is not directly accessible when saving a file in TextEdit, for example. `sudo` (short for "Super User DO") is used because Administrator privileges are needed to write to that directory.
5. Reboot your computer.

And you should be all set. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the details, but the question was *not* about ways how to modify `launchd.conf`, but rather about how all applications get the same PATH variable in a unified way.

Comment: Right, but I originally searched for the question trying to figure out how to set the `PATH` for my GUI apps, and I figured I'd help out whichever poor souls might not know how to effect the change...

Comment: You have a valid point here; still, I think *integrating* your information in the answer is the better option. - I think this comment thread becomes a meta discussion, so I've opened it on meta.stackoverflow as [What to do with an additional answer...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192192/173882)

Comment: actually, shouldn't this have been on meta.apple.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Indeed, meta.apple.stackexchange.com would've been the correct place. I just didn't know that it exists...

Answer (score -2):

You may give https://github.com/ersiner/osx-env-sync a try.

It handles **both command line and GUI apps** from a **single source**. And it works with the *latest version of OS X* (Yosemite).

Comment: Which just automates the other answer using the bit that he says does not work e.g. launchctl setenv PATH <...>

Comment: @Mark This has nothing to do with automating steps of an answer here. This one uses a Launch Agent. I suggest you give it a try.

Comment: The accepted solution uses the `launchd` system too. Your solution has the same issues as stated in the accepted answer.

Comment: @halloleo Have you actually tried it? And on which version of OS X?