# In OSX Yosemite, why can I set many environment variables for GUI apps, but cannot set the specific variable PATH

Tags: macos, launchd, path, environment-variables

After I had [sorted out OSX' PATH issues](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/87283/15340) up to the  Mavericks release, the problems come back in Yosemite!!!

So I want to mimic the old `launch.conf` feature in the new Mac OSX 10.10 Yosemite release, in order to have the PATH environment variable  in GUI apps like [Carbon Emacs](http://emacsformacosx.com) or [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com) available. I used the great idea of stackoverflow user [ursa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2078908/ursa) to set up a shell script which configures environment variables via `launchctl`. (See his stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26477515).) This works for most environment variables, **but not for the PATH variable**.

#### 1. What have I done?

First I wrote  the  `/etc/environment.rc` script looking like:

```
launchctl setenv PATH /Users/halloleo/bin:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
launchctl setenv JAVA_HOME /usr/local/jdk1.7
launchctl setenv ENVIRONMENT_RC "yes"
```

Then I created the  plists for `launchd` (listings of these and of other mentioned scripts in the appendix below). Then I activated them with

```
$ sudo launchctrl load ...
```

Then I disabled the `path_helper` utility in shell init file `/etc/`profile, so that it does not overwrite the `environment.rc` settings. And finally I restarted the machine.

#### 2. What's the effect?

When I start up Terminal the new environment variables `JAVA_HOME` and `ENVIRONMENT_RC` are set according to `environment.rc`, but PATH is set to

/usr/bin:/bin

In order to make sure, no `bash` init file got in the way I wrote a little python script instead (in the appendix as well) to show the variables in the current environment and I execute this directly by double clicking a [Platypus](https://github.com/sveinbjornt/Platypus) wrapper. Again the new variables are set, while PATH has the system default.

**So why can I set other variables, but *not* the PATH variable? And how can I solve this *in a unified way*?**

#### Update:

*The situation is very puzzling: The shell (`bash` at least) in Terminal or Emacs will pick up the PATH you set via `launchctl`, but other GUI apps will not do so., e.g. the mentioned minimal python script straight called via Platypus will not show your custom path. And even Emacs itself does not know the correct PATH: You notice this e.g. when you issue the Emacs command `M-x ispell-buffer`; the unix tool `ispell` which emacs tries to call won't be found if it is just on your custom path.*

---

#### Appendix

**`net.halloleo.environment.plist`, the launchd config file in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>net.halloleo.environment</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>/etc/environment.rc</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/etc/environment.rc</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**`net.halloleo.environment-user.plist`, the launchd config file in `/Library/LaunchAgents/`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>net.halloleo.environment-user</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>/etc/environment.rc</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/etc/environment.rc</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**`/etc/profile`, the modified bash start-up file:**

```
# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

# if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
#   eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
# fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
    [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi
```

**`show_environ.py`, the script displaying all environment variables:**

```
import os
print (os.environ)
```

Answer (score 3):

PATH in Yosemite can and should be set within /etc/paths file. Just add your path to the end of this file:

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/your/custom/path
```

/etc/environment script in [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26477515/2078908) provides support for PATH variable in GUI applications (tested with Emacs).

Comment: This does *only* work for shells which call `/usr/libexec/path_helper` during their initialisation process. GUI apps do *not* get the PATH according to `/etc/paths` - and I asked specifically about GUI apps.

Comment: I've updated answer and /etc/environment script in original post

Comment: This is two answers which one are you giving - also the OP says /etc/environment  does not work

Comment: @mark (1) after this question were rised I've updated /etc/environment, and now it does support PATH. (2) the answer here is to use /etc/paths

Comment: Sorry, ursa, for me, even if I use `/etc/environment` instead of `/etc/environment.rc`(as file name and referenced in the plists), the PATH *in the environment* of launched GUI is still `/usr/bin:/bin`. In Carbon Emacs, launched via double click in finder(!) and without a `.emacs` file, check the value of `exec-path` or `process-environment`.

Comment: ok. try in steps: (1) in terminal call "launchctl setenv PATH /your/custom/path:/bin:/usr/bin" (2) relaunch Dock application "osascript -e 'tell app "Dock" to quit'" (3) launch Emacs with spotlight (4) menu > Tools > Shell command > echo $PATH. what does it print?

Comment: Worked for me. `sudo vim /etc/paths` then reboot and worked great. Thanks.

Comment: @ursa Sorry for my late reply. When I do the four steps you suggest, I get the result you mention, but this does not mean that PATH **in Emacs' environment** is set correctly, it only shows, that the shell launched by `shell-command` gets the correct PATH. It's a very puzzleing situation. I will update the question with these details.

Comment: @halloleo that is what I would expect - the shell command in Emacs launches a new shell and that shell reads /etc/path and .bashrc etc but Emacs itself does not get called via the shell mechanism

Comment: @mark Yes, and that is exactly my point, problem and question: How can I set the environment variable PATH of GUI apps themselves when launched via the Finder? Still, no real *general* solution for this in sight...

Answer (score 2):

This puzzled me for a long time (well, the last couple of hours). In the end I ran into this bug report, which seems to exactly describe my problem (I'm not sure to what extend it's related to your problem, but there seems to be a bug in Yosemite/launchd in combination with PATH and scripts such as python:

http://www.openradar.me/18945659

The solution seems to be to start a shell script which then starts the python. Not really what I like, but it's the way it is....

Comment: Thanks for the link to the bug report. Good to now it is a real bug. I found another clutch around it; I will post it here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that launchd appends another PATH variable instead of replacing the one in the environment. Most programs use `getenv` which always returns the first occurence of a variable, shells instead iterate through all environment variables and import them as local variables thus overwriting previous instances with the last one.

This is obviously a bug in launchd, environment variables passed to a program should be unique.

Comment: Cool background answer! I guess theer is not real way around it in shells, or is there?

Comment: @halloleo You can launch the command as `sh -c 'YOUR ORIGINAL COMMAND'` which passes it though shell, picking the `PATH` set in launchd.