# How do I resolve svn: The subversion command line tools are no longer provided by Xcode

Tags: xcode, homebrew, subversion

I have subversion and Unity installed via brew.

I have code in Unity to run `svn` and it returns the error:

```
svn: The subversion command line tools are no longer provided by Xcode.
```

But if I run `svn` in Terminal, it works correctly.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that Unity wasn't receiving the correct path. I think this would be true for most applications launched from the Dock, Finder, or Spotlight (but not from the Terminal). (It's not the case for MacVim, but that's unsurprising so I didn't dig into why.)

It had this set for PATH:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

My .bashrc, .zsh_profile, etc didn't effect the PATH.

[This post explains](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/198282/268725) that on macOS you need to use launchctl to set your PATH for it to be respected by apps launched outside of a shell. Since I have svn from brew, it's in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
sudo launchctl config user path /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Once I'd done that, rebooted,  closed, and re-opened Unity, then it found my brew-installed svn.